# Why using where in indexed field is slow?

Tags: mysql, performance, optimization, where, query-performance

we have a big table. the table structure is  :

```
CREATE TABLE `visit_logs` (
  `id` int(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(10) NOT NULL,
  `ref_id` int(10) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `link_id` int(12) NOT NULL,
  `date` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `day_of_week` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `jalali_month` tinyint(2) NOT NULL ,
  `value` int(9) NOT NULL ,
  `ref_share` float(4,2) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00',
  `balance` int(9) NOT NULL ,
  `ads_id` int(12) NOT NULL,
  `ip` varchar(15) NOT NULL,
  `hash` varchar(32) NOT NULL,
  `referer` text,
  `shw` text,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `user_id` (`user_id`),
  KEY `jalali_month` (`jalali_month`),
  KEY `value` (`value`),
  KEY `ads_id` (`ads_id`),
  KEY `ip` (`ip`),
  KEY `hash` (`hash`),
  KEY `link_id` (`link_id`),
  KEY `day_of_week` (`day_of_week`),
  KEY `ref_share` (`ref_share`),
  KEY `ref_id` (`ref_id`),
  KEY `date` (`date`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

these are some sample queries :

```
mysql> SELECT count(*),SUM( value ) AS `revenue` FROM `visit_logs` where id>13197856;
+----------+-----------+
| count(*) | revenue   |
+----------+-----------+
| 10443393 | 200940970 |
+----------+-----------+
1 row in set (6.02 sec)

mysql> SELECT count(*),SUM( value ) AS `revenue` FROM `visit_logs` where `date`  > NOW() - INTERVAL 90 day;
+----------+-----------+
| count(*) | revenue   |
+----------+-----------+
| 10443354 | 200940430 |
+----------+-----------+
1 row in set (9.24 sec)

mysql> SELECT count(*),SUM( value ) AS `revenue` FROM `visit_logs` ;
+----------+-----------+
| count(*) | revenue   |
+----------+-----------+
| 23641291 | 596178719 |
+----------+-----------+
1 row in set (3.32 sec)
```

as you can see , selecting all rows is faster than selecting some row filtered by id , also filter by id is faster than filter by timestamp . id and timestamp fields are indexed !

Mysql version is 5.1 .
my.conf :

```
thread_concurrency = 8
query_cache_size = 1G
thread_cache_size = 8
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 1G
read_rnd_buffer_size = 256M
read_buffer_size = 512M
sort_buffer_size = 512M
table_open_cache = 512
max_allowed_packet = 20M
key_buffer_size = 1G
#log = /var/log/mysqlq.log
wait_timeout=120
connect_timeout=50
#max_execution_time=60000
tmp_table_size=2G
max_heap_table_size=2G
```

Explain :

```
explain SELECT count(*),SUM( value ) AS `revenue` FROM `visit_logs` where id>13197856;
+----+-------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows     | Extra       |
+----+-------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | visit_logs | ALL  | PRIMARY       | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 12978097 | Using where |
+----+-------------+------------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+----------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
mysql> explain SELECT count(*),SUM( value ) AS `revenue` FROM `visit_logs` force index (PRIMARY) where id>13197856;
+----+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type | table      | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows     | Extra       |
+----+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+----------+-------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | visit_logs | range | PRIMARY       | PRIMARY | 4       | NULL | 10604250 | Using where |
+----+-------------+------------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+----------+-------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>  SELECT count(*),SUM( value ) AS `revenue` FROM `visit_logs` force index (PRIMARY) where id>13197856;
+----------+-----------+
| count(*) | revenue   |
+----------+-----------+
| 10534567 | 202721650 |
+----------+-----------+
1 row in set (10.73 sec)

mysql>  SELECT count(*),SUM( value ) AS `revenue` FROM `visit_logs` force index (PRIMARY) where id>13197856;
+----------+-----------+
| count(*) | revenue   |
+----------+-----------+
| 10534578 | 202721830 |
+----------+-----------+
1 row in set (10.75 sec)

mysql>  SELECT count(*),SUM( value ) AS `revenue` FROM `visit_logs`  where id>13197856;
+----------+-----------+
| count(*) | revenue   |
+----------+-----------+
| 10534588 | 202722030 |
+----------+-----------+
1 row in set (3.50 sec)

mysql>  SELECT count(*),SUM( value ) AS `revenue` FROM `visit_logs`  where id>13197856;
+----------+-----------+
| count(*) | revenue   |
+----------+-----------+
| 10534592 | 202722070 |
+----------+-----------+
1 row in set (3.53 sec)

mysql>  SELECT count(*),SUM( value ) AS `revenue` FROM `visit_logs` ;
+----------+-----------+
| count(*) | revenue   |
+----------+-----------+
| 12978727 | 262590120 |
+----------+-----------+
1 row in set (1.66 sec)

mysql>  SELECT count(*),SUM( value ) AS `revenue` FROM `visit_logs` ;
+----------+-----------+
| count(*) | revenue   |
+----------+-----------+
| 12978730 | 262590180 |
+----------+-----------+
1 row in set (1.65 sec)
```

Comment: Did you run the queries multiple times? First two would load parts of the table into the key buffer and filesystem cache so the last one might be fast just because it does not have to read as much data from disk. Use [EXPLAIN](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/using-explain.html) to check if the indexes are used in your queries. And think about upgrading the MySQL version, 5.1 is quite old.

Comment: Query cache of 1G is too big, it is slow to invalidate, you should set it to ~32MB max or even disable it entirely. Sort buffers are bit too big as they are iirc allocated per-query and allocating big buffers is slower even for queries which do not need them. tmp/heap table size again too big - when some query goes over the limit, it has to transfer 2GB from memory to disk which will stall things. It it much better to fix your queries to not use big temp tables at all.

Comment: i changed settings suggested and lowered some values . but it didn't helper. i also run queries multiple times but nothing changed. i removed 50% of table records and just query time is half of before !

Comment: explain was added. it seem it don't use key !

Comment: No, the queries do not use the key. Your table contains 23M rows, the queries select 10M - using index would be actually slower than reading entire table because when index is used, rows are read in a random order from the base table but full table scan can go directly. The default limit for index usefulness is ~20% of rows to read, but is not exact as there are other effects. You can make it faster by not fetching so many rows or by usin [covering indexes](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/using-covering-indexes-to-improve-query-performance/).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using an index requires bouncing back and forth between the index and the data.

In MyISAM, each index is a BTree sitting in the .MYI file.  At the leaf node of the index is a pointer into the .MYD file.  (Or, for FIXED, it will be a record number.)  Your `SELECTs` are happy to scan linearly through the index (a BTree is efficient at that), but then for each row, it has to use the pointer to 'seek' into the .MYD file to pick up any fields that were not in the index.

Since you are fetching about half the table -- a lot of work.

Without using an index, MyISAM will scan the .MYD file (in whatever order it is in).  This is more efficient than the back-and-forth of using an index.

Normally (without `FORCE INDEX`) the optimizer will decide to do a table scan if the estimated fraction of rows to do via an index lookup is more than somewhere around 20%.  That is, *usually* the optimizer does the "right thing" by ignoring the index.

If this does not explain all the differences, then I suspect there were caching differences -- the data blocks (.MYD) cached in the OS and/or the index blocks (.MYI) cached in the `key_buffer`.

Note a difference between MyISAM and InnoDB:  For MyISAM, the `PRIMARY KEY` is stored like any other index.  For InnoDB, it is clustered with the data; so `WHERE id > ...` would be a range scan over the data, thereby more efficient, and you would not have seen 10sec times.  (There are other significant differences, too.)